# Can no longer login to Magento, Customers cannot place orders

Tags: admin, magento-1, login, security, patches

doodle-bag.com is no longer functioning, **customers cannot complete their purchases**, however **I cannot login to our Magento account to diagnose the problem**. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It *could* be you shop is/was compromised at some point so you should carefully check Magento + Webserver settings for suspicious entries, modified files, new admin users etc.

You **cannot trust** your current shop installation if it was compromised. The ultimate way to go would be a **new & clean** setup of all files on a new host/vHost with the **latest backup** before you shop was compromised.

If this is not possible due to various reasons, you might check/do these things related to this issue:

**Remove all detected changed/hacked files plus installed extensions**

Even better: Do a clean (git) checkout from your development system with the lastest version. This will be the safest unless your dev/staging system hasn't been compromised also (which is not the case if you develop locally or in a protected environment).

**Remove created backend admin accounts**

Especially for SUPEE-5344, there will also be an admin account created in the backend. Remove all new/unnecessarry admin accounts.

**Backup plan**

Depending on your backup plan and strategy, you could maybe think about a rollback of your complete database.

**Check file/folder permissions**

Did you check your file/folder permissions?
There's no need to run everything with 777 or as root user. Depending on your server configuration 400/500 can be enough. See [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html) here.

**Check server logs**

Check your webservers access/error log to trace accessed sites and suspicious URLs.
Maybe you find suspicious IP's to block on firewall level.

Answer (score 1):

Those two symptoms make me think that your shop may be compromised:

- customers cannot complete their purchases
- I cannot login to our Magento account

On top of that, according to MageReport your shop is missing a lot of the last important security patches: https://www.magereport.com/scan/?s=http://www.doodle-bag.com/

My suggestions:

- Disable your store for now by creating a `maintenance.flag` at the root folder of your webstore.
- Apply all the last security patches, you can use the official doc as a good guide to do so: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html
- Check the database `admin_user` table for any shady users that you think you have not created and delete them.
- Recreate your admin user manually via SQL by using the following code snippet (don't forget to replace the names, email, username and password values): https://gist.github.com/tridungpham/7785460
- Re enable your store by deleting the `maintenance.flag` previously created